# full calendar is not showing properly untill i click on any action button like(Month,week,day)

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar

When i resize my window it showing properly, but on refresh of my page issue is come again and I click again on button to see proper calendar.

[image: calendar issue image]

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('leave_calendar');
  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {

    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    height: 650,
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
    },
    navLinks: true,
    nowIndicator: true,
    selectable: true,
    dayMaxEvents: true,
    events: [
        {title: 'Frank',
        start: '2021-09-17',
        end: '2021-09-21',
      },
    ]
  });
  calendar.render()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.9.0/main.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.9.0/main.min.css">
<div id='leave_calendar' class="leave-calendar"></div>
```

Comment: //two ways of executing JS code after page is loaded, use "DOMContentLoaded" when able

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    //dom is fully loaded, but maybe waiting on images & css files
});

window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    //everything is fully loaded, don't use me if you can use DOMContentLoaded
});

Comment: I made you a snippet. without PHP. This is not a PHP issue and there is no jQuery

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2544810/senthil

Comment: i tryed window.addEventListener("load", function(){
but it is not working.

Comment: "not working" is not a good error description. Do you have any errors in the console? There should be no difference between "DOMContentLoaded" and "load" in your case. I suggest you make a page where you have removed EVERYTHING else from your page other than the calendar as it is in the snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the calendar to another empty page and simply include it in the PHP file its working properly, so there is only a render issue. Fullcalendar required dedicated page to render properly.